# Create an object that emits smoke only from specific faces

Tags: mesh, objects, smoke-simulation

I would like to draw an object, e.g. a cube, that emits smoke from the top face only but not the rest of the faces. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the top face in *Edit Mode* and assign it to a *Vertex Group*

[image]

- Select the Vertex group in the *Smoke Flow Advanced* section
- Limit the distance of emitting from surface by setting *Surface* to 0.

[image]